# Select Antd on hover modification

Tags: antd

Was researching for a while before asking it here, could somebody assist : I would like to change on hover color.

Something like this :

```
const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
.ant-select-dropdown-menu > .ant-select-dropdown-menu-item :hover{
background-color: green !important;
}
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
 const SelectDropdown = styled.div`
    .ant-select-dropdown-menu-item:not(.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-disabled):hover {
        background-color:  red !important;
    }
    `;

     <Select  dropdownRender={(menu =>
         <SelectDropdown>{menu}</SelectDropdown>
       )}
      >
```

If active one needs to be also same color you can do the following :

```
.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-active{
    background-color: lightgray !important;
}
```